# (Book Request) Matrix Theory

Tags: matrices, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am searching for the title and author of a book once lent to me.  I cannot recall much about it other than the color scheme used on the cover. The cover was black with orange lettering. Perhaps
there was a gray strip at the very top. [It looks somewhat like this cover.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aB59.jpg) However, as I recall, the book had some depiction of a matrix on the front cover. The title had Matrix or Matrices in it. Perhaps Theory or Applications.  If anyone knows what book I may be thinking of, a citation would be very appreciated.

Comment: [Lancaster](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/310Iw3eD-6L.jpg)

Comment: [Herstein](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41R5rSI6A1L._SY445_SX342_.jpg)

Comment: If neither of those is correct, go to amazon.com and search for "Matrix Theory" and similar.  You will get many covers to look at.

Comment: [Franklin](https://www.google.nl/books/edition/Matrix_Theory/eXQXwCDD9agC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=matrix+theory&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: If you remember the color is black, Google Images search has a possibility to restrict colors. For example, this is what I get for [matrix theory book](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=matrix+theory+book&tbs=ic:specific%2Cisc:black) or [matrices book](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=matrices+book&tbs=ic:specific%2Cisc:black).
Of course, you can try other colors, e.g., [brown](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=matrix+theory+book&tbs=ic:specific%2Cisc:brown) or [gray](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=matrix+theory+book&tbs=ic:specific%2Cisc:gray).